# Will an arborvitae grow back after I cut the trunk?

Tags: conifers, root-pruning

I had this "horizontal" arborvitaes in the front yard of the house I just moved into. I wanted to replace them with flowers.
I tried to unroot them but the roots go down just too deep and after hours shoveling I ended up cutting the last roots (to remove the trunk).

The roots were cut ~1 foot under soil level.

If I cover the roots and start planting flowers, will the trees grow back from the roots in a few years (and damage the flowers above)? Will I have to redo it all over again?

I thought of pouring some poison but I don't want to "pollute" the place for everything new I will plant.

Note: I read [Tree growing back after being cut down](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8363/tree-growing-back-after-being-cut-down) and some other questions but I felt that this was dependent on the type of the tree so I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing a photo of the plant would have been helpful to determine which type of conifer it actually was, but generally, no, there will be no regrowth. The vast majority of coniferous plants do not recover from being chopped down to the ground, unlike most deciduous plants and  other evergreens. In terms of replanting, obviously it would have been best to remove all or most of the roots so the new planting is not fighting for root room, but again, how much root room your new planting will need is down to what type of plants you mean to use.

Comment: thank you for the answer